# How to filter a csvLayer based on attributes?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Ill start out by just explaining what I'm trying to achieve. I'm running an arcgis application based on the javascript API. I'm Rendering a CSVLayer into my SceneView like such:

```
  require(["esri/Map", "esri/layers/CSVLayer", "esri/views/SceneView", "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle", "esri/Graphic", "esri/tasks/support/Query", "esri/widgets/Legend", "esri/widgets/Expand"],
    function (Map, CSVLayer, SceneView, BasemapToggle, Graphic, Query, Legend, Expand) {
  var csvLayer = new CSVLayer({
            url: numberLayers[0].Url,
            popupTemplate: template,
            featureReduction: {
                type: "selection"
            }
        });
        csvLayer.renderer = {
            type: "simple",
            symbol: {
                type: "simple-marker",
                style: "circle",
                color: [255, 255, 255, 1],
                outline: { color: [0, 0, 0, 0.4] },
                size: 16,
            },
            label: "PurpleAir Sensors",
            visualVariables: [colorVisual]
        };
  var map = new Map({ basemap: "streets-navigation-vector", layers: csvLayer });
        var view = new SceneView({
            container: "divSensorMapContainer",
            camera: {
                position: [
                    -119.289320,
                    35.216734,
                    2100000,
                ],
            },
            map: map,
            center: centerPoint,
            constraints: {
                altitude: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 9000000,
                },
            },
        });
```

What i want to do is filter this data based on the attributes defined in the CSVLayer. Ive tried doing this using the .whenLayerView function to capture the layerview and then run a .filter property to filter the dataset.

```
  view.whenLayerView(csvLayer)
            .then(function (layerView) {
              sensorLayerView = layerView;
                var newQuery = csvLayer.createQuery();
                newQuery.where = "PM25 > '40'";
                sensorLayerView.filter = newQuery;
                csvLayer.queryFeatures(newQuery).then(function (result) {
                    if (highlight) {
                        highlight.remove();
                    }
                    highlight = sensorLayerView.highlight(result.features);
                });
                view.ui.move(["compass", "zoom", "navigation-toggle"], "bottom-right");
           });
```

Now in this .whenLayerView function we get the layerview, define a query based on the data set, and then do two things:

1. Highlight sensors based on the query information.
2. Run a filter property on the layerView. (The Api reference information is given here:https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript//latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-CSVLayerView.html#filter)
   This is the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnMv3.jpg)

So does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I used a reference tutorial to get this far, you can find that here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript//latest/sample-code/featurefilter-attributes/index.html

Comment: i'm not sure to understand what's the problem is. You would like to show on the map, only the highlighted features ?

Comment: Yes, basically i want to filter the csvLayer. It doesnt work, however when i try highlighting based on the same query it works.

Comment: Link to my answer in gis.exchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/326436/87972 [This question was posted in both sites]

Answer (score 0):

The argument for the filter is just an object with the "where" property, not an ESRI query object.

So it should just be:

```
sensorLayerView.filter = {
  where: "PM25 > '40'"
};
```

This will autocast as a new [FeatureFilter](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript//latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-support-FeatureFilter.html)

Comment: Tried that as well, it doesn't work. The layer doesn't filter, however the highlight still works. Also one thing i noticed is when i try importing a FilterFeature object i get a console error.

Comment: what is the error you get in the console ? by the way, you should remove the quote around 40 in your query : `PM25 > 40`